# Using a passed parameter as part of a filename in a .bat file

Tags: batch-file

I run the following bat file at a cmd prompt:

```
x.bat 2016-05-04
```

The relevant part of the .bat file has the following:

```
@echo off
echo %1%
del evt%1%.xml
```

The `echo %1%` shows `2016-05-04` as I would expect, but the delete tries to delete a file called `evt.xml`

I have tried `del evt%%1%.xml` but that just tried to delete a file named `evt%1.xml`

How do I use the value in `%1%` as part of my filename?

Comment: Write `%1` instead of `%1%`; `%1` is the way to access the command line argument properly... anyway, what makes you think `del` tries to delete `evt.xml`? have you already removed `@echo off` for debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your file to this...

```
@echo off
echo %1
del evt%1.xml
```

You only need the % before the argument number, not after it.

See also: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php

Comment: I'm curious to know why `echo %1%` didn't output `2016-05-04%`

Comment: Oh ok - so why did it output `2016-05-04`?

Comment: Actually, I just tried your original code and it works fine, even with the unnecessary extra % sign. You need to pass a parameter to the batch file though, of course. Without one, it echos nothing for the echo %1% line. However, the single % sign is the correct approach.

Comment: That much I know - just confused as to why it output my parameter when it was looking for an environment variable - unless parameters become temporary environment variables - that would explain it.

Comment: But that wouldn't explain why it couldn't be used in the filename like that.  Going to put this one down to one of life's mysteries :-)  Thanks for your help - you solved my initial problem.

Comment: It's a matter of syntax and perhaps differing OS. Both worked fine for me on Windows 8.1.

Comment: The lines to execute are parsed by cmd.exe _from left to right_. This means that in `echo %1%` the `%1` part is _first_ changed by the parameter; _then_ the `%` is parsed, but there is not a right digit nor a right `%` to match it, so it is just removed...

Comment: @Aacini Yes, that's the behavior that I'm seeing. Not sure why it isn't working that way for Graham though.

Comment: There is no way to expand a Batch variable called "1" (`%1%`) _in a Batch file_, just in the command-line...

Comment: @Aacini that is not entirely true, when using delayed expansino, you can use `!1!` for instance.

Comment: @DennisvanGils: Yes, but delayed !expansion! have no relation with "passed parameter" `%1` expansion (that is the theme of this topic). I posted such comment as reply to a (now deleted) ManoDestra's comment that indicated that `%1%` _"expand a variable called '1'..."_, that was the reason because the OP posted _"unless parameters become temporary environment variables"_.